# Breaking 2 blocks with each click?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I break 2 blocks with just one click in creative mode. Why is this happening? I checked my touchpad and my mouse, and I found no problems at all with them.

Comment: Although I can't find an authoritative answer a few suggestions are given in [this form thread](http://www.minecraftforum.net/topic/828917-how-to-fix-double-block-single-click-issue/) that might work for you, including installing optifine and trying modifying the arguments used to launch Minecraft.

Answer (score 2):

This is because breaking blocks in creative mode is instant, so you have to click VERY lightly or else the game reads the input as a 'hold' and will continue down the line instantly breaking blocks.

Comment: If your laptop is old, it may just not be fast enough to handle Minecraft, hence the game getting confused between 'click' and 'hold'.

Answer (score 0):

It is a lag, and the game registers the one click as a double click. Therefore, two of the blocks are destroyed. It is the same issue as placing two blocks instead of one.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same problem some months ago - though i got the problem in both modes.

Destroing 2 Blocks at a time means that your game registers two hits instead of one.

The first possibilty are corrupted mod files (or a wrong configured fast click mod)

-> check your mods

The second and more propable one would be a changed driver behaviour of you mouse - most likely caused by an installation of another game or software.

-> switch the usb port you are using with your mouse and try again
    (i dont think this will be a solution for you, as you got the error on your mouse and touchpad both, but its worth a try)

At last it may be a minecraft caused error.
These occur pretty often if your game crashed anytime before.

It's a little annoying but then you have to delete the folder ".minecraft/versions" in your Appdata folder.
As you wrote a very short question without that much information, i just guess your game is running on a windows machine.
In order to get to your .minecraft folder follow these steps:

1. press [Windows]+[R] (a small window should appear on your bottom left screen)
2. enter "%appdata%" (without the " and a folder should open, called appdata/roaming)
3. scroll this folder until you see another folder called ".minecraft"
4. open it and find the "versions" folder in it
5. delete the "versions" folder NOT the .minecraft folder
6. this does not affect your minecraft maps but your lastlogin file - so just don't mind if you have to enter your password afterwords.
7. at last just start minecraft and log in - you should be done.

please write a more detailed question next time :)

Comment: The entire "bin" folder thing of your question is horribly outdated. The last version where that was still valid was 1.5 IIRC.

Comment: Im sorry youre absolutely right i forgot this -.-'
I edited this.